# Polar Plot Bounding Box Clips PolarAxes

Tags: plotting

I am using PolarPlot for the first time.  Normally I have been using ParametricPlot for this particular function but the PolarPlot offers (hopefully) better coordinate frame using PolarAxes style.

Everything seems to work but the bounding box of the frame clips the polar axes on top and bottom and left and right.  I have included a screen grab to show what I mean:
[image]

The function called gain shows the power gain of an antenna.  It accepts two arguments, theta and phi, in degrees.  I have selected theta value of 68 degrees while phi runs from 0 to 360.

I have highlighted the frame (orange outline) and notice that the polar axes are clipped.  Note that this clipping is not done by highlighting the frame.  It is like there is a bounding box that is clipping the size thus the axis degrees are clipped out on the top and bottom and left and right.

What is causing this?  I have searched and tried many things but the plot is always clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, Pi}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
  PolarAxesOrigin -> Automatic, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", None}]
```

[image]

You can add the option [`PlotRangeClipping  -> False`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html):

```
PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, Pi}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarAxesOrigin -> Automatic, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", None}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I looked all over for such an option that affected clipping -- now, why I did not see this option (i.e. PlotRangeClipping) I have no idea.  I do take issue though with the idea that the default is to clip.  It's not like extra display screen room is costing me anything.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @K7PEH, the issue does not arise in version 11.3. It seems that default option value has changed in v12.1.